# Study the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\gamma}}\left(\frac{\alpha}{n}-\frac{\beta}{n+1}\right).$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

We have to assume that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\geq0$ and $\alpha\geq\beta$.

This is what I have been able to do:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\gamma}}\left(\frac{\alpha}{n}-\frac{\beta}{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\alpha}{n(\log n)^{\gamma}}-\frac{\beta}{(n+1)(\log n)^{\gamma}}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\alpha}{n(\log n)^{\gamma}}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\beta}{(n+1)(\log n)^{\gamma}}=$$
$$=\alpha\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\log n)^{\gamma}}-\beta\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)(\log n)^{\gamma}}.$$
When $n$ is big enough, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ aren't relevant, so this can be seen as
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\log n)^{\gamma}}-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)(\log n)^{\gamma}}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n(\log n)^{\gamma}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(\log n)^{\gamma}}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\gamma}}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\gamma}}\frac{1}{n^{2}+n}.$$
Similarly, $\frac{1}{n^{2}+n}$ can be seen as $\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$, so what we are studying is
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\log n)^{\gamma}}\frac{1}{n^{2}}.$$
We notice that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ is a convergent harmonic series, so our series has to be necessarily convergent, no matter what value is given to $\gamma$.

At the end, I haven't really said nothing about the parameters, which makes me believe that my arguments are certainly wrong. I think my mistake was in assuming the associative property of addition, which is not necessary appliable here (not all the terms in the series are non-negative).

I will appreciate some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\frac{\alpha}{n}-\frac{\beta}{n+1}=\frac{(\alpha-\beta)n+\alpha}{n^2+n}$$

then we need to consider three cases

- $\alpha =  0 \implies \frac{1}{(\log n)^{\gamma}}\cdot 0=0$
- $\alpha = \beta > 0\implies \frac{1}{(\log n)^{\gamma}}\left(\frac{\alpha}{n^2+n}\right) \sim  \frac{\alpha}{n^2(\log n)^{\gamma}}$
- $\alpha > \beta \ge 0\implies \frac{1}{(\log n)^{\gamma}}\left(\frac{(\alpha-\beta)n+\alpha}{n^2+n}\right)\sim  \frac{(\alpha-\beta)}{n(\log n)^{\gamma}}$